# Checking if a field in model is modified and creating instance of another model

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I have two models

**Project Model**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    workflow = models.ForeignKey("WorkflowType", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Workflow Instance Model**

```
class WorkflowInstance(models.Model):
    workflow_step = models.ForeignKey('WorkflowStep', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

I want to check if the value of workflow field in "Project" models is added or changed for a particular project.

I am approaching the problem in following manner:

Checking if the previous and the new value of the "workflow" field in a project are different. If yes (modifies), then create the new instance of a project.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Project)
def projectToBeUpdated(sender, instance, **kwargs):

    if instance.id is None:
        pass

    else:
        previous = Project.objects.get(id=instance.id)
        if previous.workflow != instance.workflow:
            print("workflow value modified. Please create a WorkflowInstance")
```

Problem: The comparison for previous and new value of the "workflow" field are happening in "**pre_save**" signal. But my new instance creation for workflowInstance is to be created in "**post_save**" signal. How can I do this?

Also, ideally I would like to store the previous value of workflow field in "pre_save" and get the new value of the field in "post_save". Reason being, save() method might fail for any reason, while I am comparing the previous and new value in "pre_save" method itself. Making changes in the database without confirming if the **save()** method executed successfully would be a wrong approach in my view.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the model save method itself and use the following code logic, additionally if you want to identify what fields got modified you can use the dirtyfields package as well.

````
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self._state.adding:
       changed_attr = self.get_dirty_fields()
    else:
       is_new = True
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)```
````